# JS While statement in Image Slider

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to build an image slider with little buttons at the bottom that you can click and it will show the appropriate slide. So if you click button #3, it will show slide #3...pretty standard stuff. Im using javascript to detect how many slides there are and show an equal number of buttons. But now I can't figure out how to connect the buttons to the slide so that when a user clicks on one, it will show the appropriate number slide. I know this must be a pretty simple task, I just can't figure out how to set it up.

My script looks like this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var count = $(".slider_class").length;

            $("#slide_0").show();

            var i=0;
            while (i < count){
              $(".slider_bullets").append('<a href="#" id="bullet_link_' + i +'"><img src="img/slider_down.png" alt="slider_down" />');
              i++;
             }
        });
        </script>
```

.slider_class is a class I have applied to each of the slides. Each slide also has a number id  starting at zero so that the third slide is #slide_2. The .slider_bullets are the buttons I was talking about. You'll notice that I have given each of them a unique specified id as well that references the slide that they are associated with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would use.
`$(".slider_bullets a").click(function(){
   $(".slider_class").hide();
   $("#slide_"+$(this).index()).show();
});`